# Control Chrome audio from keyboard

Tags: sound, 22.04, google-chrome

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my iMac. I can control PC audio from the keyboard, but not Chrome audio. To raise or lower the audio of Chrome I have to go to settings->audio and adjust it from there: if I set the audio of Chrome to 25% and press the Audio + button on the keyboard to the maximum, the volume of Chrome always remains to 25%. I'd like to control Chrome's audio through the keyboard, but I don't know how. I search online, but I can't find anything like this.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reply but don't work, but you gave me a good idea so i solved in other way: i noticed that with the channel PCM of alsamixer i can adjust the volume of Chrome, so i went to Settings> Keyboard>View and customize shortcuts>Custom shortcuts and created the following shortcuts:

- amixer set 'PCM' 5%+ > cmd+volume up key
- amixer set 'PCM' 5%- > cmd+volume down key
  and it works!
  Thanks anyway.

Comment: You're welcome. So you wanted to control the volume for the whole system not just Chrome. That would have been much simpler if you said so in the question

Comment: No i don't want to control volume for the whole sysyem, but by volume up and volume down keys i set Master channel and, after my changes, by cmd+volume up and cmd+volume down i set PCM channel  and consequently Chrome volume, so i solved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any builtin shortcut, and there is separate volume control that will appear for each tab. But here is a custom solution with scripts:

1. Paste the following into `~/.local/bin/chromevolumeup`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
pactl list sink-inputs | tr \\n \\f | grep -Po 'Sink Input #\K\d+(?=([^\f]|\f\t)+Chrome)' | xargs -I_ pactl set-sink-input-volume _ +10%
```

2. Paste the same thing into `~/.local/bin/chromevolumedown`, except with `+10%` replaced with `-10%`
3. Open both files' properties and mark as executable
4. [Add a keyboard shortcut](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en) for each command